Seeed Studio MR24HPC1 mmWave Human Detection Sensor Kit
I have added the Seeed Studio MR24HPC1 mmWave Human Detection Sensor Kit in Home Assistant ESPHome. The ‘Presence Information’ entity value always shows as ‘Detected’, even though I am out of range of the sensor. Does anyone know how to fix this? What changes need to be made in the ESPHome yaml configuration? Below is a part of my ESPHome yaml code for this entity:
binary_sensor:

    platform: seeed_mr24hpc1
    has_target:
    name: “Presence Information”

I tried adding filters in the yaml code, placed the sensor kit at different heights and angles, but still it always shows 'Detected'.
